# The first element will error message to go on focus. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with some input fields:

```
Folder Name:
<input type="text" id="folderName" name="folderName" data-bind = "value: FolderName" />

Prefix:
<input id="prefix" name="prefix" data-bind = "value: Prefix" />
```

I validate those fields using jquery validation plugin:

```
rules: {
            folderName: {
                required: true
            },
            prefix: {
                required: true,
                exactLength: 4
            },
}
```

When submitting the form with empty fields, error messages are displayed for both inputs. What I want to accomplish is the first element with error message to go on focus. My skills in javascript are rather poor so any working example will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drop something like this after your validation fires

```
// set focus to first input
$('body').find(':input:first').focus();
```

Comment: As far as I can see this sets the focus to the first input element. I want to set the focus on the first element which has error message.

Comment: @Mdb im not very familiar with the plugin you are using, but i would assume they append some class to each element that failed validation. in that case, you would use `$('body').find('.failedClass:first').focus();`

Comment: Yes, You are right! Unfortunately I am using the tab widjet from the JQuery UI Plugin and the element I want to be on focus is on the second tab and it never goes there. Maybe I should try to find a way to select that tab when element in it is on focus but that is a different question from the one I asked here. Thank You for your help.